# Is registry restored after a system restore?

Tags: windows-registry, system-restore, windows-7-restore

This one is straightforward. After restoring a system using system restore, are registry keys and data get restored as well?

Interested in Win7 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, system restore keeps and restores backup copies of the registry.

In fact, the registry backups can be used without system restore if your system has a corrupt registry.  They are stored in the "c:\system volume information" folder.

Microsoft documents the procedure to restore just the registry manually here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Restore):

> The following resources are backed up:
>
> - Registry
> - [...]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are restored to state when selected restore point was created.

Be sure you have drive C monitored by system restore (Volume Shadow Copy).

Answer (score 1):

The Registry is part of the SystemState and is backed-up as well as restored with it.